# Pipe system sound to another computer

Tags: audio, alsa

I have no speakers in my PC (Cent-OS 5.5) but there is a stereo speaker connected to the computer next to my computer (also Cent-OS 5.5). Both computers are networked. Is there any way to pipe my system sounds to that computer's speaker?

Answer (score 3):

`Pulse Audio` has the functionality you're looking for.  See the [Network Documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network).  CentOS packages are available in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Answer (score 3):

You can "pipe" over netcat like so:

Client: `nc -vv -l 9000|mpg123 -v -` (9000 is the port to listen on)

Server: `nc -vv serverIP 9000 < /path/to/audiofile`

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe your music to the speakers of the other computer.

See something similar here, but with the microphone:

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/350/output-your-microphone-to-a-remote-computers-speaker

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out one of [netJACK](http://jackaudio.org/netjack) solutions.